# Is there in vivo evidence of Amyloid beta toxicity?

Tags: neuroscience, neurodegenerative-disorders

Amyloid beta is thought to be toxic, however from a brief search, this is based on (1) in vitro (2) measurements of some proxies of toxicity (e.g. [Ultrasensitive Measurement of Ca2+ Influx into Lipid Vesicles Induced by Protein Aggregates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5615231/) referenced in Wikipedia).

My impression is that we do not have any high-quality evidence that amyloid beta is toxic in vivo and that there is significant circumstantial evidence against it being toxic (links below). Is this correct?

1. ["30% of elderly people have #Alzheimers pathology (plaques &/or tangles) but no disease"](https://twitter.com/sxbegle/status/1233380365852606464)
2. [There's an elderly woman with large amounts of amyloid plaques but no symptoms of Alzheimer's](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/04/health/alzheimers-treatment-genetics.html)
3. According to Derek Lowe ["all of those amyloid-antibody trials have ended in grievous, expensive failures"](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2019/06/06/a-missed-alzheimers-opportunity-not-so-much)

Answer (score -1):

From a [quick search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11&q=Amyloid%20beta%20toxicity%20in%20vivo&btnG=), it seems that there is plenty of solid evidence for *in vivo* toxic effects. A couple of papers [here](https://academic.oup.com/jnen/article/63/3/255/2916596) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0969996102904857).

Comment: An answer is expected to stand for itself with references being useful for further reading. Your "answer" is basically one sentence containing three links. Please edit it to avoid its deletion. This also applies to some of the other answers you wrote recently.

Comment: You can delete them if you want! ;)

Comment: @TumbiSapichu - we'd rather not delete them, and we appreciate your efforts. However, posts as this are below our standard and not conform our guidelines. If you don't improve these posts we will have to delete them.

Comment: @TumbiSapichu The aim is not to delete postings - which the mods could easily do - but to improve the quality. If this doesn't happen, it might be the last resort.